# How can I melt a matrix data frame in R with 2 variables and 1 value column?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, reshape2, melt

My data looks like this:

```
    col1 col2 col3 
col1 100  25  30  
col2 25  200  50
col3 30  50   300
```

where the column and row names are c("col1", "col2", "col3")

I want it to look like this:

```
Var1 Var2 Value
col1 col1 100
col1 col2 25
col1 col3 30
col2 col1 25
col2 col2 200
col2 col3 50
col3 col1 30
col3 col2 50
col3 col3 300
```

I'm trying reshape2::melt but it's not giving me the results I'm looking for `melt(df)`, any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` with `as.data.frame` after creating the attribute for `table`

```
as.data.frame.table(m1)
#   Var1 Var2 Freq
#1 col1 col1  100
#2 col2 col1   25
#3 col3 col1   30
#4 col1 col2   25
#5 col2 col2  200
#6 col3 col2   50
#7 col1 col3   30
#8 col2 col3   50
#9 col3 col3  300
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(100L, 25L, 30L, 25L, 200L, 50L, 30L, 50L, 300L),
.Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("col1", "col2", "col3"), c("col1", "col2", 
"col3")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidyr package is what you need

```
library(tidyr)

df <- gather(df, 'Var2', 'Value' 2:4)
```